# How to send notification mail each time the user logs in with firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send a notification mail (or any medium) each time the user logs in to the react app. Currently, I am using

```
Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async(userData) => {
  if (userData) {
    const sendMail = await api.sendMail(userData.email);
  }
}
```

But the issue with this each time I refresh the app, it calls sendMail API.
So I thought I will do this on login button click, but the issue with that is its a social login.
And I am using `signInWithRedirect` like  `Firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(facebookProvider);`.
In this case, I don't have the past state of my app.
Is there any way to do this signInWithRedirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not want to trigger this [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#onauthstatechanged) because, as you pointed out, this will send emails anytime the user's signin state changes.

Since you are using Facebook to authenticate users, you'll want to look at the auth events and methods available to Firebase's [federated identity provider integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login). In this case, you should trigger the email during [`signinWithPopup`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) or `getRedirectResult` if using `signInWithRedirect`.

Example using `signinWithPopup`:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(async result => {
    const user = result.user;
    const sendMail = await api.sendMail(user.email);
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
});
```

Example using `signInWithRedirect`:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(async result => {
    if (result.credential) {
        const user = result.user;
        const sendMail = await api.sendMail(user.email);
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back. But it's not possible to do this with`signInWithRedirect`?

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't know about `getRedirectResult`. Thanks. Wanted to clarify, getRedirectResult is not a bad practise to use it in `onAuthStateChanged`? Is there a best practise?
```Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async(userData) => {
      const result = await Firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
      if (result.credential) {
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
      }
```

Comment: No don’t put it in there. Probably best to put it in `componentDidMount()` since the user will be redirected back to your site.